# Missing features in the Android app

Tags: discussion, android-app

I downloaded the [Stack Exchange mobile app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) a couple of weeks ago - and I've noticed it's missing quite a lot of features.

I've also noticed that there's another app called [SoClient](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sudosaints.stackoverflow) which actually has more features, and is not an official app by Stack Overflow.

**Are there any plans to improve the app?**

Personally - when on my mobile device - I just use the app to get push notifications, but I rather use the site using my mobile browser, rather than the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel that the app needs a new feature, you can post a feature request on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com), tagging it with "feature-request" and "android-app".

Of course, you should first check if the feature hasn't been asked already, in which case you can just upvote the request. Or even put a bounty on it, if you have the points.

I'm probably preaching to the choir here, but: just post one feature request at a time, and consider them carefully before posting.

> Are there any plans to improve the app?

Both the Android app and the iOS app are actively being developed by Stack Exchange. Our requests on MSE are considered for this.