# Data not refreshing when browsing on mobile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, mobile-web

I'm browsing Stack Overflow and other Stack sites on my mobile device quite often.
I'm not using the mobile app - I rather use the website with mobile web browsers. In my case: Chrome in Android (I've also mentioned why in this question: [Missing features in the Android app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345131/missing-features-in-the-android-app)).

The thing that's bothering me on the mobile web page, when using mobile browsers, doesn't refresh automatically with fresh data (Recent achievements, inbox messages, new comments, updates and more) like it does on desktop browsers. The only way to get fresh data is to refresh the page.

I know it's a small issue but it's kinda annoying and data usage consuming in opinion, and seems pretty easy to implement.

Comment: That sounds like a good thing to me as it limits the amount of data used on a mobile device where bandwith may be limited and overall data usage may have limits.

Comment: @JoeW Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: Are you specifically asking for this to be implemented on the mobile site? Or are you just looking for a "workaround"? 'cause you can use the desktop/full site on your mobile browser, and it works just fine. I always use the full site on Android Chrome.

Comment: @MikeM. I believe that as mobile browsers are more and more common, I'm speaking on behalf of a huge amount of users, so I guess this should be properly implemented and not as a workaround.